# how to perform clustering in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dataframe looks like below:
[image: data]
my dataframe has lot more rows.
what I want to perform is to cluster over each location.
I want to write a loop which first extract the location "A" and then perform clustering on 'Capacity' and 'Sale' columns.

```
location    name    capacity    sale
A   Stonecrystal    50  3.915434493
A   Valtown 200 5.410339205
A   Fairley 200 6.793002265
```

I have tried the below code, but by only manually do this process for Location 'A'.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_excel('ClusterData.xlsx')

locations = {k:v for k,v in dataset.groupby('location')}


location1_ = locations['A']
location1 = location1_.iloc[: , 2:4].values


from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation

af = AffinityPropagation().fit(location1)
labels = af.labels_
centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
centers = af.cluster_centers_
num_clusters = len(centers)
```

how can I write a loop to do this process for each location.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have found it:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation

dataset = pd.read_excel('ClusterData.xlsx')

districts = {k:v for k,v in dataset.groupby('location')}
district = dataset['location'].unique()

for j in district:
    dis = {}
    dis[j] = districts[j].iloc[: , 2:4].values
    af = AffinityPropagation().fit(dis[j])
    labels = af.labels_
    centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
    centers = af.cluster_centers_
    print(j)
    print('Number of Clusters: ', len(centers))
    print('Labels: ', labels)
    print('Centers: ', centers)
```